Why does my cat dig at my bed when I sleep?
Usually I wake up to my cat clawing at my blanket, my side of my body, arms, my hands if she can and she does some kind of aggressive kneading? Like you can hear her claws go into the fabric and than her ripping them out. I figured it's because shes hungry and wants food but I give it to her and she still keeps doing it and doesn't eat until later. So I have no clue why she does it and it's on a regular basis but only in the morning.

The simple answer is your cat can see that you are about to wake up and start kneading just because she is happy to see you.
Intense emotions like happiness and fear can be hard to control for people and even more so for cats, so aggressive kneading is just a result of happiness.
Most cats have some type of ritual in the morning when their owner wakes up, kneading is one of the positive ways to wake up in the morning in my opinion.
Kneading is a sign the cat is happy and relaxed, kneading in cats starts when they are newly born and it makes the mother's milk flow (respect to female cats that handle all of the needle-sharp claws and milky teeth at the most sensitive part of their body).

Kneeding can also become a learned behavior; "when I do this, Mom wakes up and cuddles me." We have some control over which behaviors we actively reinforce...
